# Adding to dictionary within for loop: not incrementing

Tags: python, dictionary

Essentially, I want to store the following XML input into a dictionary.

Extract of input (variable *xml_tree*)

```
<listingContentIndexEntry>
    <active>true</active>
    <lastUpdatedDate>2015-05-05</lastUpdatedDate>
    <listingHomeAwayId>/listings/0000/2671f21e-16a7-45c9-a6b7-d94ca801db24</listingHomeAwayId>
    <listingUrl>http://www.a.url</listingUrl>
</listingContentIndexEntry>
<listingContentIndexEntry>
    <active>true</active>
    <lastUpdatedDate>2015-05-05</lastUpdatedDate>
    <listingHomeAwayId>/listings/0000/849302c1-8734-4540-8169-57d71a309dc8</listingHomeAwayId>
    <listingUrl>http://www.a.url</listingUrl>
</listingContentIndexEntry>
<listingContentIndexEntry>
    <active>true</active>
    <lastUpdatedDate>2015-05-05</lastUpdatedDate>
    <listingHomeAwayId>/listings/0000/7fbfa33c-3371-4850-9c21-6a7685dd0ae1</listingHomeAwayId>
    <listingUrl>http://www.a.url</listingUrl>
</listingContentIndexEntry>
<listingContentIndexEntry>
    <active>false</active>
    <lastUpdatedDate>2015-05-05</lastUpdatedDate>
    <listingHomeAwayId>/listings/0000/336b4e46-e710-49a0-a192-ab66e320fe89</listingHomeAwayId>
    <listingUrl>http://www.a.url</listingUrl>
</listingContentIndexEntry>
<listingContentIndexEntry>
.........
```

My code so far is

```
xml_tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

#parse xml
for listingContentIndexEntry in xml_tree.iter('listingContentIndexEntry'):
    active = listingContentIndexEntry.find('active').text
    lastUpdatedDate = listingContentIndexEntry.find('lastUpdatedDate').text
    listingId = listingContentIndexEntry.find('listingId').text
    listingUrl = listingContentIndexEntry.find('listingUrl').text


    data = {'listingId':listingId,'active': active,'lastupdateDate': lastUpdatedDate}
    id_dict.update(data)
```

The data is being read in from the XML correctly (I have printed to screen) but when I print the dictionary, it is only showing one entry when there should be several hundred.

```
{'lastupdateDate': '2015-06-23', 'listingId': '/listings/0000/c5666884-c74f-4b89-831a-e285720e611c', 'active': 'false'}
```

How can I add mutiple entries to the dictionary?

Comment: You store only ONE data in your code... `.update` will always refresh the same dict object ...

Comment: It seems like you want something like a list of dictionaries.

Comment: please post a sample of what the correct result would look like.

Comment: @Sam yeah or maybe a dict of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.update` method  just adds the new elements of dictionary to previous dict, and also updates already set values if same `key` is encountered in old dict.

```
dict1 = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7}
dict2 = {'Sex': 'female', 'Age':19 }

dict1.update(dict2)
print "Value : %s" %  dict1
```

Output is :

```
Value : {'Age': 19, 'Name': 'Zara', 'Sex': 'female'}
```

You see here the old age is replaced by new age.
Similarly in your code new `keys` are not being set, always previous set keys are being updated.
If you would like to get all results make change `id_dict` to `id_list` a list and use `id_list.append(data)` insted.

Comment: Thank you, I did this using the info in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23826330/545966