# Python Looping over an argument in a function

Tags: python, function, loops, xero-api

I am being a noob trying to loop over a function from pyxero:

```
invoices = xero.invoices.filter(page = 1)
```

The above call returns a list of dictionaries which becomes blank when there are no more pages left: [] . So the iteration would stop when the count of elements in the current list/page would become 0. I am trying to loop and create one big list that contains the elements from page 1 and 2 etc appended

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152431/iterating-over-list-of-dictionaries

Comment: Hi, thanks, I ended up doing a while loop which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, (page needs to be string):

```
number = 1
list = []
data = xero.invoices.filter(since = datetime(2018, 1, 1), page = str(number))
while len(data) > 0 
    data = xero.invoices.filter(since = datetime(2018, 1, 1), page = str(number))
    list.append(data)
    number += 1
```