# Getting multiple list based on the different keys from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
temp = [
    {
        "item": "apple",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "item": "ball",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "item": "cake",
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

I want two lists:

```
["apple", "ball", "cake"]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Can we do this using list comprehension?

I have done like this:

```
list_item=[]
list_id=[]
for val in temp:
    list_item.append(val["item"])
    list_id.append(val["id"])
```

Comment: Hi there. Could you please share what you've done so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152431/iterating-over-list-of-dictionaries)

Comment: Not really @Sushanth

Comment: I have updated in the description @BalajiAmbresh

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure you've seen Suraj's post by now.

Answer (score 2):

Use the dictionary key `item` to store values in `l1` and `id` to store values in `l2`.

```py
q = [
    {
        "item": "apple",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "item": "ball",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "item": "cake",
        "id": 3
    }
]

l1 = [dic['item'] for dic in q]
l2 = [dic['id'] for dic in q]
```

In a single loop :

```py
l1,l2 = [],[]
for dic in q:
    l1.append(dic['item'])
    l2.append(dic['id'])
```

Comment: Can we do it in a single for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
x =  {"item": "apple","id": 1}
y = json.loads(x)
a[0]=y["item"]
b[0]=y["id"]
```

you can try like that

See this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp